# APT wanting to remove a package and upgrade it

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04.

After doing an `apt-get update` (without errors), APT wants to upgrade a package and in the same time wants to remove it:

```
$ apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libsystemd-journal0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsystemd-journal0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 49,9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 176 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

If I remove the package (manually or with `apt-get autoremove`), then update and upgrade, the result is the same.

It seems a kind of cycle, and since days ago, each time I update and upgrade, the symptom is repeated.

**How can I solve it?**